# How can I dynamically add an HTML overlay to a table row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have the table structure given below:

```
<table>
      <tr id="Row1">
         <td class="Column1">Column</td>
         <td class="Column2">Column2</td>
     </tr>
      <tr id="Row2">
        <td class="Column1">text</td>
        <td class="Column2">Image</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I hover over the column I need to show the following menu as an overlay over the first column

```
<div class="drawer" style="display:none;">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Products</a></li><!-- active link changes -->
      <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Orders Complete</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the script you've tried and explain what was wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `position:relative` for the `<tr>`, `position:absolute` for the menu (*to take it out of normal flow, So that the table cells won't jump around*) and append the menu to the respective `<tr>` which is hovered.

something like the following:

```js
$("table tbody tr").hover(function(event) {
  $(".drawer").show().appendTo($(this).find("td:first"));
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".drawer").hide();
});
```

```css
tbody tr {
  position: relative;
}
.drawer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="Column1">Column</th>
      <th class="Column2">Column2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="Row1">
      <td class="Column1">text</td>
      <td class="Column2">Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Row2">
      <td class="Column1">text</td>
      <td class="Column2">Image</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="drawer">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    <!-- active link changes -->
    <li><a href="#">Information</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Orders Complete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Side note: I also took the liberty to separate the heading into `<thead>` and data into `<tbody>`, and moved the inline styles to CSS. The script will work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it doesn't require any changes to your existing HTML / CSS:

```
$('.Column1').mouseover(function(e){

  $('.drawer').css({
    'display': 'block';
    'position': 'absolute';
    'left': e.pageX;
    'top':e.pageY;
  });
}).mouseleave(function(e){
  $('.drawer').css({
    'display': 'none';
  });
});
```